# How can I scrape/download many files from a dynamic webpage with a hidden xhtml section?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, xhtml

I am trying to download every CSV file on this site: http://data.cnmc.es/datagraph/jsp/inf_trim.jsp

Each CSV is in a radio button inside a sub-page (not a different site) of that main page (I believe the term used to describe this type of site is 'dynamic'). Example of location of one of the CSV files:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWx90.png)

Problem:
When I run the following code in python in jupyter notebook in order to find patterns in the html - so that I can automate the file downloading process - *only a small part* of the html is retrieved.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webpage = 'http://data.cnmc.es/datagraph/jsp/inf_trim.jsp'
response = requests.get(webpage)
html = response.text
print(html)
```

What it retrieves:

```
...some code above which I have purposefully removed for post...
<noframes>                                                                                            
  <h1>Informe Trimestral</h1>
  <p>Aplicaci&oacute;n de consulta de los informes que elabora trimestralmente la Comisi&oacute;n Nacional de los Mercados y la Competencia (CNMC)) en relaci&oacute;n al mercado de las telecomunicaciones en Espa&ntilde;a</p>

  <h2>Trimestral IV 2014</h2>
  <p>1. DATOS GENERALES DEL SECTOR</p>
  <p>2. INFRAESTRUCTURAS</p>
  <p>3. COMUNICACIONES FIJAS</p>
  <p>4. COMUNICACIONES M&Oacute;VILES</p>
  <p>5. SERVICIOS DE TELEVISI&Oacute;N Y RADIO</p>
  <p>6. SERVICIOS MAYORISTAS</p>

  <h3>EL SECTOR</h3>

  <h2>COMUNICACIONES FIJAS</h2>

  <h2>COMUNICACIONES M&Oacute;VILES</h2>

  <h2>AUDIOVISUAL</h2>

  <p>2014 © CNMC Comisión Nacional de los Mercados y de la Competencia.</p>  
</noframes>
...some code below which I have purposefully removed for post...
```

What I can see using 'right-click > inspect' on the site:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QUSj.jpg)

As you can see, the 'right-click > inspect' html shown is much more extended (i.e. it includes `<a>` tags to dynamically navigate the page which the code-retrieved html does not).

***How can I fetch ALL of the html, including those `<a>` tags?***

I believe the answer/problem may lie in this line of code (complete guess, have no clue really):
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xAVy.jpg)

FYI: please correct me if my strategy is not good. My intention is to get the full webpage html to find a pattern in the html tags that will allow me to automate the process of clicking on each CSV radio button using the selenium library

Thanks for your time

Jaime

Comment: screenshots of code is a big No-No. [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have now changed the code block to not be a screen shot, how about the html that is retrieved, should that be a code block as well?